# Is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=0$ when $f$ is an even function?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

If f(x) is an even function (also, $f$ is continuous and Riemann integrable), does that mean that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) dx = 0 $$ If so, why? This has been puzzling me for a while.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Clarify, perhaps you mean $f$ is continuous and integral is Riemann!.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have been more specific. $f$ is indeed a continuous function and is also Riemann integrable. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @tattybojangler Consider that $f(x)=1$ is an even function, it is continuous (and therefore integrable) yet the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) dx = 0$ diverges.

Comment: @tattybojangler Are there continuous functions that are not Riemann integrable?  Did you mean that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\,dx$ exists as an improper Riemann integral?

Answer (score 2):

You need an additional constraint which is $\int_{0}^{\infty}{x f(x) dx}$ shall be defined.

If it is, you can trivially do:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x f(x) dx} = \int_{-\infty}^0{x f(x) dx} + \int_{0}^{\infty}{x f(x) dx}$$

Then if you change $x \rightarrow -x$, it gives (as $f(-x) = f(x)$):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x f(x) dx} = \int_{+\infty}^0{-x f(-x) (-dx)} + \int_{0}^{\infty}{x f(x) dx} = \int_{+\infty}^0{x f(x) (dx)} + \int_{0}^{\infty}{x f(x) dx}$$

and finally:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x f(x) dx} = -\int_0^{+\infty}{x f(x) (dx)} + \int_{0}^{\infty}{x f(x) dx} = 0$$

But $f$ being Riemann integrable on $\mathbb R$ is not enough. For example, let us take $f$ defined with:

$$\forall x \in \left[-1; 1\right], f(x) = 1\\
\forall x \in \left]-\infty; -1 \right[ \cup \left]1; \infty\right[, f(x) = \frac 1 {x^2}$$

We do have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f(x)dx} = 4$ because $-\dfrac 1 x$ is a primitive outside $[-1; 1]$ but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x f(x) dx}$ is not defined...

Answer (score 1):

No. My answer is similar to the example given in the comments above, although I did think of the example by myself. Let $c>0$ be a constant.

Let $f(x)=c$. $f$ is even. Is it true that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x) \, dx$ is zero? Actually the integral does not converge.

Answer (score -1):

$y(x)=x$ is an odd function of $x$. The product of an odd function and an even function must be an odd function, so $y(x)=xf(x)$ is an odd function if $f(x)$ is an even function of $x$. The integral of an odd function in a symmetric interval (symmetrical about $x=0$) must be zero. Thus the integral of $xf(x)$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ must be zero.